# I want to enable tracing only for aspx pages with PageOutput false attribute in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

Is that possible that i can made some filters so that asp.net tracing is enabled for only specific pages.

Because now i need to search the aspx pages out of hundreds of images and other files on which i can get details in the trace.axd.

Thanks

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your web is deployed over IIS,this [post](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/tracing) gives a detailed steps how to enable tracing over specific contents